# jQuery Mobile - Android Back button prompt confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, cordova

I have a jQuery mobile app (about 7 HTML pages). I want to change the back button functionality in Android (using Eclipse with Phonegap). I tried all `@overwrride` but it won't work properly.

I would like on every page, when the back button is hit, to get a prompt: "Are you sure you want to exit?" Yes and No options.

Now I have this script that exits the app completely.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
  }
  function onBackKeyDown() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way to have inside the function `onBackKeyDown()` a jQuery window popup and have an if condition, where you click yes to execute `navigator.app.exitApp();` or cancel if you hit no?

I am new to this, so I really appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you could do this :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
}

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No"); // Prompt the user with the choice
}

function onConfirm(button) { 

    if(button==2){ //If User selected No, then we just do nothing
        return;
    }else{
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // Otherwise we quit the app.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!! I added the code but back button now gets me back to the previous page. in Eclipse in LogCat i get the error: Unable to add window — token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?
Do you have any suggestions what else i need to add? I don't have anything in the activity file, except splash screen, and in the manifest i require permission only for internet and networking.
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: yes, The code above that I posted works fine. It exits the app on any page, it doesn't go back...

Comment: @user2370024 I forgot to add `e` when calling `onBackKeyDown()`. Add it and tell me if it works.

Comment: @user2370024 Do you still call this document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); inside the deviceready handler ? On every page ?

Comment: no, i have the code that you provided only on the main page index.html

Comment: @user2370024  You have to have it on every page.